# Posting data with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

If there are 2 form fields in a page with 2 different submit buttons how do I tell to cURL which form to submit?

Example

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
   <input type="text" name="age">
   <input type="submit" name="agree">
   <input type="submit" name="disagree">
</form>
```

My code so far

```
//create array of data to be posted
$post_data['age'] = '5';
 
//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no needing to know which form in HTML must be posted.

Form can be determined by Method, Action and/or Set of fields.

P.S. Clicked named submits are sending too. So add `post_data['agree'] = '';`.

P.P.S. Don not use it for spam.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and let php's curl extension do the dirty work of encoding etc.

This saves you from encoding the string!

`curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);`

Comment: Yes but what about specifying which submission button to click?

Comment: `$post_data['agree'] = 'Submit'` where `agree` is either agree or disagree :)

Comment: Name of submit button is a key in $_POST array. Simply set it and specify some dummy value, e.g. "Submit"